# Disposing is causing Fatal Signal 11

Tags: libgdx, dispose, screens

In my libgdx game, I have multiple screens. I am a little unsure how to properly use the `dipose()` method.

In each screen there are certain variables I create then dispose in the `dispose()` method. I read online that if I do not dispose, it causes memory leaks and crashes the program.

But, for some reason, whenever I dispose anything in my `MenuScreen`, it causes a crash in the app (`Fatal signal 11`). (The error also occurs at other random times when switching different screens). I don't know if this has anything to do with me naming my files the same names in each class.

For example, in the `create()` function of each class I do this:

```
batch = new SpriteBatch();
shapeRenderer = new ShapeRenderer();
```

Then in the `dispose()` function of each class I do this:

```
batch.dispose();
shapeRenderer.dispose();
```

Does keeping the same variable name in each class affect my code? Aside from this I dispose every image, sound and font manually.

Even when I do not dispose anything in my `MenuScreen` class, the `Fatal Signal 11` error occurs every now and then when switching screens.

Sorry for being vague but I am unsure what is causing this error. There is also an approximate 1 second delay when switching screens.

Note:

When switching screens, I do:

```
game.setScreen(new ScreenName(game));
```

while `game` is just an instance of my `MainClass`:

```
final MainClass game;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are passing the instance of your main class, why do you make a new batch in each class? Just use the main class's batch